# How to insert page identification into a comments table?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, forms

I'm trying to create commenting system with multiple pages (each page has its own comments).
For example - two pages for visitors: alegro.php and darwin.php

alegro.php

```
<?php 
$page="alegro"; // this variable should identify a page
include "comments.php";
?>
```

darwin.php

```
<?php 
$page="darwin";
include "comments.php";
?>
```

comments.php has a commentForm and some js validation code.
Then comments.php send all to the fourth file - submit.php, which populates dbTable:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments(page,name,url,email,body) VALUES (
      '$page' // - this is my first try
       $page  // - the second try
'".$arr['page']."' //the third try (after implementing a hidden "page" field into the form).
'".$arr['name']."',
'".$arr['url']."',
'".$arr['email']."',
'".$arr['body']."'
)");
```

Anyway - `$page` value is not written into the table.

Comment: do you have the field type correct for 'page'?

Comment: Have you used `global $page;` before attempting to access it?

Comment: @Dogbert, $arr is defined in `submit.php. All others fields in the table are populated normally.

Comment: @romo, yes the field `page` works well if populated manually

Comment: @TomWalters, no, I didn't use `global $page`. Should I ?

Comment: Yeah go ahead and add it before you attempt to access it, and try again.

Comment: If `comments.php` is submitting a form to another page, then `$page` won't be accessible.  Try adding the `$page` value in a hidden form element then it will be apart of the submit data and available in `submit.php`

Comment: @TomWalters, i tried: `global $page;`  `$page="alegro"; - without result

Comment: Ah yes, I misunderstood, @AaronW. is correct, the `$page` variable isn't available once you submit to another file, maybe use a session variable, or a hidden input to pass it around?

Comment: @AaronW, i wrote in the question, - i tried to implement hidden field into the form. Thanks, anyway

Comment: Could someone write a short example.

Comment: @Alegro I don't see that in your question. You'll need to provide more code from all your files for more help.

Comment: @AaronW., look at sixth row from the bottom and its comment

Comment: @AaronW., finally - solved. And in short - your code is ok. It would take a long to describe where was the error. Thanks a lot for your effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**darwin.php**

```
$page = 'darwin';
include('comments.php');
```

**comments.php**

```
<form action="submit.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="<?php echo $page; ?>" />
    <textarea name="comment"></textarea>
</form>
```

**submit.php**

```
// $arr array filled
$arr['page'] = $_REQUEST['page'];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments(page,name,url,email,body) VALUES (
    '".$arr['page']."',
    '".$arr['name']."',
    '".$arr['url']."',
    '".$arr['email']."',
    '".$arr['body']."'
    )");
```

FYI - don't use mysql_* as it's being deprecated.  Switch to [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) functions.

Comment: Aaron, all values are in the table, except `$page`. I used your code and checked all. Two lines `<input type="hidden" name="page" value="<?php echo $page; ?>" />` and `'".$arr['page']."',` shuld be the solution, but...

Comment: How can I check if `$page` is present in hidden field at all ?

Answer (score 2):

why are  you using `$page` ?

just do inserting function likie that

```
 function insertdata (){
  // do your code of inserting here to database
 }
```

and in every file `darwin` or `alegro`  just include this function .

exempel

```
    if (isset($_POST['submit_comment']))
      {
      function insertdata() ;
      }
```

Comment: goodmood, your approach is completely new. I will tray at the end. Hare i have php file which write to database on the server.